# Missing email subject

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I have two python scripts where the first extracts data from local weather stations into a text file and the second inserts the text file contents into the email body. The contents of the file appear as shown in the expected output below but I get ‘no subject’ in the Subject field. I used the basic email package at https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html.

First script:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import datetime as dt

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/RAH/61%2c55/forecast') as url:
    data = json.load(url)
    iso_date = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(
        data['properties']['periods'][0]['endTime'])
    utc_date = iso_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')
    time_of_day = data['properties']['periods'][0]['name']
    temp = data['properties']['periods'][0]['temperature']
    rel_humidity = data['properties']['periods'][0]['relativeHumidity']['value']
    sf = data['properties']['periods'][0]['shortForecast']
    df = data['properties']['periods'][0]['detailedForecast']
    weather_report = (
        f"This is a weather report for North Raleigh: \n\nDate of forecast: {utc_date}\nTime of Day: {time_of_day} \nTemperature: {temp} \nRelative Humidity: {rel_humidity} \nShort Forecast: {sf}
\n
Detailed Forecast: {df}")

with open("weather.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(weather_report)
```

Second script:

```
from data import extract_data
import smtplib, os
from email.message import EmailMessage
from dotenv import load_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv()

extract_data()

email_address = os.environ.get("gmail_username")
email_password = os.environ.get("gmail_password")

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = f'Daily Weather Report'

sender_email = email_address
receiver_email = "my_email@gmail.com"
password = email_password

with open("weather.txt", "r") as my_file:
    file_content = my_file.read()

server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, file_content, msg)
server.quit()
```

This is what I get:

```
(no subject)

my_email@gmail.com
    
Date of forecast: Feb 17, 2024
Time of Day: This Afternoon
Temperature: 51
Relative Humidity: 36
Short Forecast: Partly Sunny
Detailed Forecast: Partly sunny, with a high near 51. Northwest wind 8 to 12 mph.
```

This is the expected output:

```
Daily Weather Report

my_email@gmail.com

Date of forecast: Feb 16, 2024
Time of Day: Overnight 
Temperature: 42 
Relative Humidity: 76 
Short Forecast: Partly Cloudy 
Detailed Forecast: Partly cloudy, with a low around 42. West wind 2 to 6 mph.
```

Comment: Are you just asking about why you get `(no subject)` instead of `Daily Weather Report` or also why the `Date of forecast` and subsequent lines are different?

Comment: You're calling `sendmail()` with the wrong arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem not long ago...  I found it easier to use the **smtplib.SMTP.send_message()** function instead of **smtplib.SMTP.sendmail()**.  You  first have to put all information (*subject*, *from*, *to* and *content*) in the message itself.  Then send the message using send_message().

I reproduced your code (using my own server and credentials) and I got a message with a subject.

So here is my suggestion for your second script:

```
from data import extract_data
import smtplib, os
from email.message import EmailMessage
from dotenv import load_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv()

extract_data()

email_address = os.environ.get("gmail_username")
email_password = os.environ.get("gmail_password")
sender_email = email_address
receiver_email = "my_email@gmail.com"
password = email_password

with open("weather.txt", "r") as my_file:
    file_content = my_file.read()

# Part 1: Prepare the message
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = f'Daily Weather Report'
msg.set_content(file_content)  # <--- set the content of the message
msg["From"] = sender_email  # <--- set the origin address
msg["To"] = receiver_email  # <--- set the destination address

# Part 2: Send the message
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email, password)
server.send_message(msg)  # <--- use this function instead
server.quit()
```

I hope it works for you!